# Using download button on web using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba

```
        <div id="CSV"
            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; clear: left;"> 
            <input onclick="go('CSV')" type="button"
                value="Download in CSV Format" />
            </li>
        </div>
```

Trying to download the file by using the **onclick** function. I have tried the following code, it executes but doesn't download the file.

```
Set x = ie.document.getElementById("CSV")
x.Click
```

Also x.onclick gives error and x.FireEvent "onclick" also doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: The I'd excel isn't there, CSV is, but you need tagname of a

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Sorry I have edited that but problem is still the same. There is no tag name and I don't know why but the website still works when I click it manually?

Comment: `'CSV'` is the ID of the parent element (the div) that houses the input element. You need to target the `<input>` tag - not the `<div>` tag

Comment: @MacroMan I was trying that only for quite sometime but the GetElementsByvalue does not work and I think it isn't a valid function. There is no other identifier left and that's the reason I am stuck. Most of the time I match the innertext and use navigate function but not here.

Comment: @Jain `GetElementsByTagName("input")` ;) - That will return a `Collection` object though of all `<input>` elements so you will have to loop through and test the properties of each one to get the one you want. Then you can use the `.Click` method.

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set div = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
'loop through all the elements
For Each x In div
    ' check if the value matches the required value, if it does then use the .click function. 
    If Trim(x.Value) = "Download in CSV Format" Then
        x.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Your contribution would have more value if you add some explanation why the suggested approach solves the problem. The logic may not be apparent to everyone...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS selector of

```
input[onclick=go('CSV')]
```

This says get the `input` tag with property `onclick= go('CSV')`.

[image: CSS selector]

This can be deployed as

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[onclick=go('CSV')]").Click
```

The [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method applies the CSS selector to the HTMLdocument.